# Loading gif overlay when php page is processing

Tags: php, image-processing, overlay

I have a link that loads a php page full of processing images and overlays using imagemagick.  Is there a way to have the current page you are on have a loading please wait overlay where it overlays or lets user know to wait?

I have seen this attached to an image but not when you click a link to a page.  It's not a form submission either which I've seen solutions for.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good Jquery plugin to achieve this. It is called Queryloader. It acts like a page preloader. Refer the below link,

[Query loader - Page preloader](http://www.gayadesign.com/diy/queryloader-preload-your-website-in-style/)

Comment: I tried that and it's not working.  I think my problem is deeper.  I click a link on page A...  page A sits there waiting for about 40 seconds to load page B.  Page A switches to Page B and then processes the image for about 6 seconds which is fine.  The initial switch is longest waiting time.  So the loading script only works on the part that takes about 6 seconds.  I need to figure out what's happening when clicking link on page A I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

try to send a request to the content page through ajax on document.ready function and show the loading image and when the content of that page is received hide the image and show the content.